# How can I add ticket variable and discount variable to calculate total trip cost?

Tags: python

```
# The options for where the user wants to go.
options = str(input("Where would you like to go? "))

if options == "Hawaii":
    print("You have selected: Hawaii")
elif options == "hawaii":
    print("You have selected: Hawaii")
elif options == "bahamas":
    print("You have selected: The Bahamas")
elif options == "Bahamas":
        print("You have selected: The Bahamas")
else:
    print("Avaliable locations are: Hawaii or the Bahamas.")

ticket_price = 2300

discount = 0

# The airlines that are available to the user.
print("1. Us Air")
print("2. Delta")
airline = str(input("Which airline would you like to choose? "))

if airline == 1: 
        print("You have selected US Air")

elif airline == 2:
        print("You have selected Delta Airways")
else:
    print("There are no available airlines at this moment")
    
    # Here is where how many tickets are needed based on how many people are going on the flight.
passengers = int(input("How many people are joining for this flight? "))

if passengers == 1:
    print("You have selected one passenger.")
elif passengers == 2:
    print("You have selected two passengers.")
elif passengers == 3:
    print("You have selected three passengers.")
else:
        print("Maximum number of passengers for a single order is 3.")
        

# Here is the chance that you or someone is your group is under the age of 18, and can qualify for a 25% discount.

discount = str(input("Are you or any passengers under the age of 18? "))
if discount == "Yes":
    print("Congrats you qualify for a 25% discount!")
elif discount == "yes":
    print("If so how many?")
    int(input(""))
    print("Congrats you qualify for a 25% discount!")
else: 
    print("Confirmed, no one is under the age of 18")

ticket_cost = (ticket_price*discount* 0.25)
```

Comment: That is unclear what the problem is, [edit] your post and explain

Comment: Welcome to SO, to get your issues resolved, don't just put the code https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

After getting all the information, you may compute the total price

```
ticket_cost = passengers * ticket_price
```

Taking into acount the *under 18* part :

```
discount = input("Are you or any passengers under the age of 18? ")
passengers_under_18 = 0
if discount.lower() == "yes":
    print("Congrats you qualify for a 25% discount!")
    passengers_under_18 = int(input("If so how many?"))
else:
    print("Confirmed, no one is under the age of 18")

ticket_cost = (passengers - passengers_under_18) * ticket_price +  passengers_under_18 * ticket_price * 0.25
```

Comment: It doesn't calculate the discount when I run it. Is there another part to it?

Comment: @SUB_ROSA read last line, it multiply the cost by 0.25 for the amount of children